# ctypes pass string by reference: string is not updated

Tags: python, reference, ctypes

I want to pass the reference to a string from python to a c program. The c program writes something to the string and I want to read it back in python.
The c program looks like:

```
void foo(char *name) {
    name = "Hello World";
}
```

And the Python script:

```
>>> import ctypes
>>> lib=ctypes.CDLL('libfoo.so')
>>> name=ctypes.create_string_buffer(32)
>>> print name.value

>>> lib.foo(name)
>>> print name.value

>>>
```

I'd expect "Hello World" after the second `print`.
I'm sure it's simple, but I can't figure out what's wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your C code changes the value of the pointer, rather than changing the buffer. Remember that C parameters are passed by value so modifying a parameter can never result in changes that can be seen by the caller.

Anyway, you just need to use `strcpy` to copy your string into the buffer provided.

```
void foo(char *name) {
    strcpy(name, "Hello World");
}
```

Obviously in real code you'll want to pass the buffer length too so that you can avoid buffer overruns.